# How can I mount a remote drive that I can only access via SSH agent forwarding?

Tags: server, mount, ssh, ssh-agent

I apologize if the question title is unclear.

To clarify, I have to SSH into server1 and then SSH from there into server2. Server2 is where the folder I need to mount is located. I've tried setting the tunnel up using Putty and PAC Manager, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

My public key is already on both servers and I can authenticate just fine to both while using the -A flag to access server1.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I don't know what kind of log/config I'd need to copypasta here, but I will provide them if requested.

I was told I could do this by someone who set it up correctly on a Mac with Secure Pipes and Fuse. I have Fuse on this installation, as well as SSHFS.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT TO REFUTE POSSIBLE DUPLICATE FLAG: The only way I see the 'duplicate' post being helpful is if I'm supposed to use the proxy command host as the sshfs host.

Comment: I can already SSH into both. I don't need a proxy command; I need to mount a folder on my local machine that exists on server2.

Comment: Then just mount it with sshfs. I don't see the issue here...

Comment: So I'd need to use the proxy command host, since I can't access server2 directly from local?

Comment: Exactly. That should work